# Generate binary matrices which are distinct up to reflections

Tags: code-golf, linear-algebra, matrix, abstract-algebra, binary-matrix

Here are all the 2x2 binary matrices

```
#0  #1  #2  #3  #4  #5  #6  #7  #8  #9  #10 #11 #12 #13 #14 #15
--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  
00  00  00  00  01  01  01  01  10  10  10  10  11  11  11  11  
00  01  10  11  00  01  10  11  00  01  10  11  00  01  10  11
```

Two binary square matrices are equivalent under the relation `~` if one can be mapped onto the other by **any number of reflections in the horizontal or vertical axes**.

`#1 ~ #2` under reflection in the vertical axis so we only need to keep one of these (it doesn't matter which). Likewise `#3 ~ #12`, `#6 ~ #9` and so on.

**THE GOAL** is to produce a program which takes a single input `N` and prints as many `N x N` binary matrices as exist such that all matrices in the output are distinct under the above relation.

In hand-wavey pseudocode, an admissible solution would be

```
define M[i] = N by N matrix with bit pattern equal to i

for i = 0 to (2^(N^2)) - 1
    valid = true
    for j = i+1 to (2^(N^2)) - 1
        if (equivalent(M[i], M[j]))
            valid = false
            break
    if (valid)
        print (M[i])
```

For the input `N=2` one valid output would be

```
00  00  00  01  10  01  11
00  01  11  01  01  11  11
```

But by selecting different matrices from the same equivalence class another valid output would be

```
00  10  11  11  11  10  01
00  00  00  10  11  10  10
```

The order of matrices doesn't matter, the particular choice from equivalent matrices doesn't matter, and whitespace doesn't matter, output the matrices however you like as long as it's human-readable.

**The output must be exhaustive.**

<del>Shortest code wins.</del>

EDIT: this is my first golf post and I've changed my mind on the winning criteria.

Shortest code in a language *not specifically designed for conciseness/golfing* wins.

I hope it's not bad etiquette to change this criterion post-hoc, but I think doing it in a "normal" language is a much more *interesting* proposition.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is a nice first challenge, but I'd recommend letting people output the result in a flexible format (e.g. each matrix as a list of lists). That way people can focus on the very interesting core of the challenge (finding the unique matrices up to symmetries) instead of also having to worry about formatting the output (which could easily take just as many bytes and make the golfing of the main challenge less important).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, both of you, I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I'd also recommend posting future challenge ideas [in the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where you can get feedback for it before the challenge goes live and people might start working on it.

Comment: Out of interest, why exclude rotations?

Comment: I was tempted to include rotations as an equivalence. I was also tempted to include inverting each bit as an equivalence. I was also tempted to include permutations of rows/columns as an equivalence. In the end, I made an arbitrary decision to keep the requirements fairly simple. Feel free to post a variation.

Comment: [We've discussed this in the past](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7473/12012) and ruled *against* excluding or penalizing certain languages in code golf competitions, meaning that challenge that do so should be considered off topic. Furthermore, [the accepted answer is the answer that wins the challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8712/12012), which means shortest code for code golf questions. Summarizing: If you don't want to accept any answer *at all*, then don't. However, if you accept an answer, it has to be the shortest one.

Comment: Finally, [the J language](http://www.jsoftware.com/) is *not* a golfing language, but a high-level, general-purpose, high-performance programming language that has existed for 25 years. Even with your current rules, you've still accepted the wrong answer.

Comment: It's your choice. Meanwhile I change my vote from +1 to -1

Comment: Fair enough on J, @Dennis I accepted that one. My 2 cents on this issue is: if a language *advertises itself* as a golfing language then that's a bit cheeky. To respond to [the analogy in the accepted answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/disallowing-explicit-exclusion-of-languages), it's like going to a rifle range and asking people to actually *hold the gun* rather than use a tripod-mounted-stepper-motor to aim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## J, <s>66</s> <s>56</s> 53 bytes

```
[:~.,~{.@/:~@(2:_&(][:,(;|.;|."1)&>)<)@$"#.2#:@i.@^*:
```

Brute-force search.

### Usage

```
   f =: [:~.,~{.@/:~@(2:_&(][:,(;|.;|."1)&>)<)@$"#.2#:@i.@^*:
   f 2
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│0 0│0 0│0 0│0 1│0 1│0 1│1 1│
│0 0│0 1│1 1│0 1│1 0│1 1│1 1│
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
   # f 3
168
   # f 4
16576
```

### Explanation

```
[:~.,~{.@/:~@(2:_&(][:,(;|.;|."1)&>)<)@$"#.2#:@i.@^*:  Input: integer n
                                                   *:  Square n
                                           2      ^    Compute m = 2 ^ (n ^ 2)
                                               i.@     Make a range [0, m)
                                            #:@        Convert each to binary digits
    ,~                                                    Pair, make [n, n]
                                       $"#.            Reshape each binary list
                                                          to a matrix with size [n, n]
             (                       )@                Operate on each
                                    <                    Box it, call x
              2:                                         The constant 2
                _&(                )                     Repeat that many times on x
                       (        )&>                        For each box
                            |."1                             Reverse by column
                         |.                                  Reverse by row
                           ;                                 Join them
                        ;                                    Join with initial
                    [:,                                    Flatten
                   ]                                       Return that as the new x
         /:~@                                          Sort each
      {.@                                              Take the head of each
[:~.                                                   Unique and return
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ṛ€;U;
2ḶṗṗµWÇ³¡Ṃµ€Q
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bma4oKsO1U7CjLhuLbhuZfhuZfCtVfDh8KzwqHhuYLCteKCrFE&input=&args=Mg)

#### How it works

```
2ḶṗṗµWÇ³¡Ṃµ€Q  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

2Ḷ             Unlength 2; yield [0, 1].
  ṗ            Cartesian product; construct all vectors of {0, 1}^n.
   ṗ           Cartesian product; construct all vectors of ({0, 1}^n)^n.
               This yields A, the array of all binary n×n matrices.
    µ     µ€   Begin a new, monadic chain and apply it to all matrices M in A.
     W           Wrap; yield [M].
      Ç³¡        Call the helper link n times, initially with argument [M], then
                 on the previous return value.
         Ṃ       Take the minimum of the results.
               This replaces all matrices with the lexicographical minimum of their
               equivalence classes, mapping equivalent matrices to the same matrix.
            Q  Unique; deduplicate the resulting array of matrices.

Ṛ€;U;          Helper link. Argument: L (array of matrices)

Ṛ€             Reverse the order of the rows of each M in L.
   U           Reverse the order of the columns of each M in L.
  ;            Concatenate the resulting matrix arrays.
    ;          Concatenate the result with L.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

<s>Wanna look for  better way of getting all the reflections.</s>

*Thanks to @Pietu1998 for golfing me 2 bytes!*

```
hM.gS+K_Bk_MMKcRQ^`T*
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hM.gS%2BK_Bk_MMKcRQ%5E%60T%2a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3&debug=0).

Going to wait for golfing before doing a full explanation, but it essentially makes all possible binary matrices, then `.g`roups them by the sorted list of all the possible reflections, then only takes one from each group.

Comment: If I run that with argument `3` the output begins `[['000', '000', '00'],` note the missing zero at the end.

Comment: @spraff whoops, I did `^2Q` instead of `Q^2`. fix saves me a byte too :D

Comment: @spraff fixed it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do `_MM` instead of `mC_Cd`.

Comment: @Pietu1998 oh yeah, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 195 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(p=1<<n*n)].map(_=>(p++).toString(2).slice(1)).filter((s,i,a)=>![1,0,1].some(c=>a.indexOf((c?b.reverse():b=b.map(s=>[...s].reverse().join``)).join``)<i,b=s.match(eval(`/.{${n}}/g`))))
```

Returns strings representing all matrix entries concatenated e.g. `111101111` represents a 3×3 matrix of `1`s with a `0` in the middle. Explanation:

```
n=>[...Array(p=1<<n*n)].map(            Enumerate all binary matrices
 _=>(p++).toString(2).slice(1)          Convert to padded binary
).filter((s,i,a)=>![1,0,1].some(        Check reflections of each matrix
 c=>a.indexOf((c?b.reverse():           Reverse the order of lines
  b=b.map(s=>[...s].reverse().join``    Or reverse each line
  )).join``)<i,                         Has this been seen before?
 b=s.match(eval(`/.{${n}}/g`))))        Reshape string into a square
```

Comment: A recursive number-to-binary function is exactly the same length: `.map(f=(x=p++)=>x>1?f(x>>1)+x%2:"")`

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 100 bytes

```
import Data.List
r=reverse
e#n=mapM id$e<$[1..n]
f n=nubBy(\a b->elem a[r b,r<$>b,r$r<$>b])$"01"#n#n
```

Usage example: `f 2` -> `[["00","00"],["00","01"],["00","11"],["01","01"],["01","10"],["01","11"],["11","11"]]`.

How it works:

```
e#n=mapM id$e<$[1..n]        -- helper function: creates a list of all combinations
                             -- of the elements of e of length n
                             -- "01" # 2 -> ["00","01","10","11"]

                   "01"#n#n  -- creates all binary n x n matrices
nubBy                        -- remove duplicates according to the equivalence
                             -- relation
   \a b ->                   -- a equals b if
       a elem                -- a is an element of
         [r b,r<$>b,r$r<$>b] -- the list of reflections of b
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 94 bytes

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[{0,1}~Tuples~{#,#},Sort@Join[Join@@Outer[Reverse,{#},{1,2,{1,2}},1],{#}]&]&
```

Comment: Hi JHM! Thanks for the answer. I don't understand Mathematica very well, so could you add a bit of explanation as to what's going on? (I posted the same thing on your other recent answer. Giving some explanation is a strong expectation for answers on this site)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 184

This turned out to be quite similar to Neil's, but all in all the bag of tricks in javascript is not so diverse.

```js
n=>eval("r=x=>[...x].reverse();for(l='',i=m=1<<n*n;i<m+m;i++)a=i.toString(2).slice(1).match(eval(`/.{${n}}/g`)),[b=a.map(x=>r(x).join``),r(a),r(b)].some(x=>~l.search(x))?0:l+=a+`\n`")
```

*Less golfed*

```js
n=>{
  r = x =>[...x].reverse();
  for(l = '', i = m = 1<<n*n; i < m+m; i++)
    a = i.toString(2).slice(1).match(eval(`/.{${n}}/g`)), // base matrix as an array of strings
    b = a.map(x => r(x).join``), // horizontal reflection
    c = r(a), // vertical reflection
    d = r(b), // both reflections
    // check if already found 
    [b, c, d].some(x => ~l.search(x)) // using search, arrays are converted to comma separated strings 
      ? 0 
      : l += a+`\n` // add new found to list (again as a comma separated string)
  return l
}
```

*Test* Beware, even for input 4 the running time is overly long

```js
f=n=>eval("r=x=>[...x].reverse();for(l='',i=m=1<<n*n;i<m+m;i++)a=i.toString(2).slice(1).match(eval(`/.{${n}}/g`)),[b=a.map(x=>r(x).join``),r(a),r(b)].some(x=>~l.search(x))?0:l+=a+`\n`")

function update() {
  var i=+I.value;
  
  result = f(i)
  count = result.split('\n').length
  O.textContent = count+'\n'+result
}

update()
```

```html
Input <select id=I onchange="update()"><option>2<option>3<option>4<option>5</select>
<pre id=O></pre>
```